# Installing matlab 2012b on ubuntu 12.10-java error

Tags: 12.10, java, matlab

I have matlab 2012b iso file and I tried mounting it and install ..but i get the following error...

```
    root@karthik:/home/karthik# mount -t iso9660 -o loop /home/karthik/Downloads/matlab.iso /media/mathworks
    mount: warning: /media/mathworks seems to be mounted read-only.
    root@karthik:/home/karthik# cd /media/mathworks
    root@karthik:/media/mathworks# ./install
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Error: Cannot locate Java Runtime Environment (JRE).
    The directory /media/mathworks/sys/java/jre/glnx86/jre does not exist.

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

What could be the problem??

Comment: okay i c that the directory actually doesnt exist......it seems to be glnxa64 instead of glnx86....

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the installer is searching for a 32-bit version to install (`x86`) but only finds an AMD64 version (`a64`). Is it possible that you try to install a 64 bit Matlab on a 32 bit Ubuntu? Then you should download a 32 bit installer instead.